# Is possible to write something like that "f<N> can compile only when N>0"?

Tags: c++, templates

for example, I can check if N is > 0 at compile time like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
template<int N>
struct Is{
    enum{Positive=N>0?1:0};
};

template<>
    struct Is<0>{
};

int main(){
    printf("%d\n",Is<3>::Positive);
    printf("%d\n",Is<-3>::Positive);
    return 0;
};
```

which filter 0 by forcing Is<0>::Positive cannot compile, but is there any method (e.g.:template,macro....) that force Is< N >::Positive cannot compile when N is not > 0?

Comment: It is possible via specialization with an enabler (SFINAE-like) or `static_assert`, but in your case, why not just take a `unsigned` type ?

Comment: Why do you want a `Positive` enum value that is always 1 for the case where the code compiles. What purpose does that serve?

Answer (score 6):

`static_assert(N > 0, "N must be greater than zero")`